# Coldfusion loop over insert query values

Tags: mysql, coldfusion, cfquery, cfloop

I am trying to loop over an insert query. I'm looping over the values to the return results are within a list.

```
<cfquery datasource="#OLMSdatasourceWrite#" result="myResult">
    INSERT INTO OLMS_Data_RatioScenarios
    (
        OLMS_Account_ID,
        OLMS_RatioScenario_Name
    )
    VALUES
    (
    <cfloop list="#AccountListWithSettings#" index="CurrentAccount">
        (<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_numeric" value="#CurrentAccount#" maxlength="255">, <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_clob" value="#requestBody.value#" maxlength="255">)
        <cfif CurrentAccount GT 1>
           ,
        </cfif>
    </cfloop>
    )
</cfquery>

<cfoutput>Inserted ID is: #myResult.generatedkey#</cfoutput>
```

The problem im running into here is that it keeps putting a "," after the final iteration

```
VALUES ( ( (param 1) , (param 2) ) , ( (param 3) , (param 4) ) , ( (param 5) , (param 6) ) , )
```

I need help figureing out the cfif statement to prevent this(NOTE: if i put the cfif above the query params it started the loop out like (,(param 1),(param 2),

Comment: You have your answer.  I'm merely going to point out that you should double check what the `index` attribute of looping through a list actually represents.  Also, if you insert more than one record, are you sure that `myResult.generatedkey` will give you what you need?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to track the number of items in the list and check that the current item's position is less than the length of the list:

```
<cfset numItems = ListLen(AccountListWithSettings)>
<cfset i = 1>

<cfloop list="#AccountListWithSettings#" index="CurrentAccount">
  <!--- Stuff inside of loop --->

  <!--- ...and then --->
  <cfif i lt numItems>
    ,
  </cfif>

  <cfset i++>
</cfloop>
```

Update, per @Leigh's comment: you can also take this approach. I add it as a 2nd approach because even though it's simpler, it's not usually how my mind thinks through this particular problem. To each his own. :)

```
<cfset i = 1>

<cfloop list="#AccountListWithSettings#" index="CurrentAccount">
  <cfif i gt 1>
    ,
  </cfif>

  <!--- Stuff inside of loop --->

  <cfset i++>
</cfloop>
```

Comment: thats for the quick feed back, i changed it up and it threw this error:

Type:Expression
Message:You have attempted to dereference a scalar variable of type class java.lang.String as a structure with members.
Caught an exception, type = Expression

Comment: Oops, I was looking at it as a query. Need to finish this coffee. Will update my answer.

Comment: Tip: You can simplify a bit, and eliminate the numItems check, by using `<cfif i gt 1>,</cfif>` and moving it to the beginning of the loop.

Comment: @ChrisPeters - Fair enough. I have used it so long I find it more readable, but agree it is one of those subjective things :)  Side note, they *finally* added support for tracking position with array and lists loops in CF2016. So no more manual incrementing of counter variables (yay!).  http://trycf.com/gist/0e76e27359cf1b2d4f875fa84194eb50/acf2016?theme=monokai

Comment: @Leigh Awesome! I say to Adobe: too little, too late. :)

Comment: @ChrisPeters - Lol, I swear a request has been out there in one incarnation or another since around CF9, probably CF7 ;-)